# QAction.triggered change value of variable by defining dynamic items in context menu and connect in pyqt5 in python

Tags: pyqt5, contextmenu

```
def generateContext(self):
    menu = self.textedit.createStandardContextMenu()
    menu.clear()
    action1 = menu.addAction("Grammar")
    Spell= QMenu('Spell Suggestion')
    menu.insertSeparator(menu.actions()[1])
    menu.insertMenu(menu.actions()[1],Spell)
    Spell.addAction(action1)
    cursor = self.textedit.textCursor()
    cursor.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
    self.textedit.setTextCursor(cursor);
    word = cursor.selectedText();
    for words in self.lists():
        #action = Spell.addAction(words)
        action = Spell.addAction(words)
        rec = lambda item =words: self.Correct(item)
        action.setCheckable(True)
        action.triggered[bool].connect(rec)
    menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())
```

The list which dynamically items adding in context menu by for loop

```
def lists(self):
    listSpel=['san francisco','atlanta','london']
    return listSpel
```

The correct method which triggers when user click on the menu item

```
def Correct(self,words):
    print(words)
    cursor = self.textedit.textCursor()
    cursor.beginEditBlock()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is your problem exactly, but maybe this will help:

```
for words in self.lists():
      action = QAction()
      action.setText(words)
      action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.Correct(words))
      Spell.addAction(action)
```